# How to print info messages in dart:test?

Tags: dart

When writing tests with `dart:test` how to print info messages such that they appear interleaved with tests output?
If I use `print` then it prints in the end, after all tests output.

Looking for analog of `info()` in `ScalaTest`.

Answer (score 1):

After [clarification](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/1070) with guys from the `dart:test` dev team it looks like regular `print` can be used. You just need to pass the `--reporter=expanded` argument when running

```
pub run test test/shimlaw_tests_test.dart --reporter=expanded
```

By default a compact single-line reporter is used which places output of `print` in the end of the test runner output. While the expanded reporter prints appropriately.